# Unplanned greedy behaviour in uu-parsinglib

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, parser-combinators, uu-parsinglib

**The problem**

I came across a problem today and I do not know how to solve it. It is very strange to me, because the code I've written should (according to my current knowledge) is correct.

So below you can find a sample parser combinators. The most important one is `pOperator`, which in very simple way (only for demonstration purposes) builds an operator AST.
It consumes "x" and can consume multiple "x" separated by whitespaces.

I've got also `pParens` combinator which is defined like:

```
pPacked pParenL (pWSpaces *> pParenR)
```

so it consumes Whitespaces before closing bracket.

**Sample input / output**

The correct input/output SHOULD be:

```
in: "(x)"
out: Single "x"

in: "(x )"
out: Single "x"
```

but I'm getting:

```
in: "(x)"
out: Single "x"

in: "(x )" 
out: Multi (Single "x") (Single "x")
--  Correcting steps: 
--    Inserted  'x' at position LineColPos 0 3 3 expecting one of ['\t', ' ', 'x']
```

but in the second example I'm getting error - and the parser behaves like it greedy eats some tokens (and there is no greedy operation).

I would be thankful for any help with it.

**Sample code**

```
import Prelude hiding(lex)
import Data.Char hiding (Space)
import qualified Text.ParserCombinators.UU as UU
import           Text.ParserCombinators.UU hiding(parse)
import qualified Text.ParserCombinators.UU.Utils as Utils
import           Text.ParserCombinators.UU.BasicInstances hiding (Parser)


data El = Multi El El
        | Single String
        deriving (Show)


---------- Example core grammar ----------

pElement     = Single <$> pSyms "x"
pOperator    = applyAll <$> pElement <*> pMany (flip <$> (Multi <$ pWSpaces1) <*> pElement)

---------- Basic combinators ----------

applyAll x (f:fs) = applyAll (f x) fs
applyAll x []     = x

pSpace    = pSym ' '
pTab      = pSym '\t'
pWSpace   = pSpace <|> pTab
pWSpaces  = pMany pWSpace
pWSpaces1 = pMany1 pWSpace
pMany1 p  = (:) <$> p <*> pMany p

pSyms []       = pReturn []
pSyms (x : xs) = (:) <$> pSym x <*> pSyms xs

pParenL     = Utils.lexeme $ pSym '('
pParenR     = Utils.lexeme $ pSym ')'
pParens     = pPacked pParenL (pWSpaces *> pParenR)

---------- Program ----------

pProgram = pParens pOperator
-- if you replace it with following line, it works:
--  pProgram = pParens pElement
-- so it seems like something in pOperator is greedy

tests = [ ("test", "(x)")
        , ("test", "(x )")
        ]

---------- Helpers ----------

type Parser a = P (Str Char String LineColPos) a

parse p s = UU.parse ( (,) <$> p <*> pEnd) (createStr (LineColPos 0 0 0) s)

main :: IO ()
main = do 
    mapM_ (\(desc, p) -> putStrLn ("\n=== " ++ desc ++ " ===") >> run pProgram p) tests
    return ()

run :: Show t =>  Parser t -> String -> IO ()
run p inp = do  let (a, errors) =  parse p inp
                putStrLn ("--  Result: \n" ++ show a)
                if null errors then  return ()
                               else  do putStr ("--  Correcting steps: \n")
                                        show_errors errors
                putStrLn "-- "
             where show_errors :: (Show a) => [a] -> IO ()
                   show_errors = sequence_ . (map (putStrLn . show))
```

**IMPORTANT**

```
pOperator    = applyAll <$> pElement <*> pMany (flip <$> (Multi <$ pWSpaces1) <*> pElement)
```

is equivalent to:

```
foldr pChainl pElement (Multi <$ pWSpaces1)
```

according to: [Combinator Parsing: A Short Tutorial](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/doaitse-swierstra/combinator-parsing-tutorial.pdf)

And it is used to define operator precedense.

Comment: I don't have a good solution, but your description seems to be exactly what's happening.  If I define `let pOperator    = applyAll <$> pElement <*> (pMany (flip <$> (Multi <$ pSome pWSpace) <*> pElement) <|> pure [])` I get the expected result, so `pMany` appears to be committing to another match after matching the space.

Comment: @JohnL: That's very strange. Please notice that replacing `pProgram = pParens pOperator` with `pProgram = pParens pElement` gives good result (that of course does not solve the problem either), but it shows, that `pMany` CAN work as expected - can consume no elements.

Comment: @JohnL: additional the problem cannot be solved with `... <|> pure []`, because it works only for 1 character input, it fails for example for `(x x )`.

Comment: Ok, the problem "can be theoretically solved" by replacing the library `pMany` combinator with custom one and replacing a lot of library functions (like `pChainl` etc to use our custom `pMany` combinator). This is of course ugly solution, but it works so far. I would love to see the proper one. The custom `pMany` can be declared as follows: `pMany p  = (:) <$> p <*> pMany p <|> pure []`

Comment: Again a work around, but could pMany be replaced with pList_ng?

Comment: @OllieB: Yes, this gives exactly the same behavior as my custom `pMany`

Answer (score 1):

The definition of pMany reads:

```
pMany :: IsParser p => p a -> p [a]
pMany p = pList p
```

and this suggest the solution. When seeing the space we should not commit immediately to the choice to continue with more x-es so we define:

```
pMany :: IsParser p => p a -> p [a]
pMany_ng p = pList_ng p
```

Of course you may also call pList_ng immediately. Even better would be to write:

```
pParens (pChainr_ng (pMulti <$ pWSpaces1) px) --
```

I did not test it since I am not sure whether between x-es there should be at least one space etc.

Doaitse